# Dropdown list Getting rows in Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

This dropdown list value and button. When you click the button the first value will be remove and the second value will be echo in

```
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;

   <p id="demo"></p>
```

its working fine but i want to get the rows in my database depened on what is the id demo.  Any help will be appreciated thank you

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>

<?php
require('connection.php');
   $positions=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbPositions")
 or die("There are no records to display ... \n" . 

  mysql_error()); 
?>
  <td><SELECT NAME="position" id="position" onclick="getPosition(this.value)">
<OPTION VALUE="select">select
<?php 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($positions)){
echo "<OPTION VALUE=$row[position_name]>$row[position_name]"; 

}
?>
</SELECT></td>
</form>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Remove option with index "1"</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
 <script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("position");
x.options.remove(0);
var x = document.getElementById("position").options.item(0).text;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;


 }
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
 </script>


  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Are you asking, if you can get the value from database for id, which was echoed ?

Comment: yes. is it posible?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: please tell me how. I've tried to make research but it's not working when i apply it on mine.

Comment: I have posted answer, let me know, if you have any specific questions. Please free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display result from the database on the same page, then you need to use `AJAX` to call asynchronously to get the data from database on the same page.

So, let say, you have wrote a method `displayResult()`, which sends request and get result from database. That you need to call at the end of `myFunction()` and from here you pass the `demo` value.

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("position");
x.options.remove(0);
var x = document.getElementById("position").options.item(0).text;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  displayResult(x); // calling method to get result.
 }
```

Now, how to write code to make ajax request? There are many tutorial and posts. You can refer them.

Comment: @ArkaneArkane any specific reason for reverting ?